# SEND clip as keystrokes

Tags: vbscript, powershell-2.0, clipboard, clip, keystroke

I am just wondering if there is any way in manner of PSH or VBS to paste/SEND the text from clipboard as separate keystrokes rather then string????

It is VERY important, since I have to do some automatic search in web UI drop down lists and passing text by CTRL+V simply does not work. So I need to send each letter as unique keystrokes.

Tried to find some way and searched over the Internet but no luck.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to interact with the clipboard in VBScript. Here's one way to read clipboard text:

```
strText = CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
```

Once you have the text, you could simply send each letter in sequence:

```
For i = 1 To Len(strText)
    SendKeys Mid(strText, i, 1)
Next
```

Comment: Be blessed Bond, that's EXACTLY what i need.